# Finding a Mobius Transformation mapping the unit circle to $y=-x$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck trying to find a mobius transformation that maps points on the unit circle to the line $y=-x$. I've started by setting up the cross-ratio, with $z_1=1$, $z_2=i$, and $z_3=-1$, along with $w_1=i-1$, $w_2=0$, $w_3=1-i$. The equation I've set up is 
$$\frac{(z-1)(i+1)}{(z+1)(i-1)}= \frac{(w-i+1)(i-1)}{(w-1+i)(1-i)}.$$
Solving for $w$ yields 
$$w=\frac{(i+1)z+i-1}{zi-1}.$$
It's easily verified that this doesn't perform the mapping I was looking for. Was this probably some algebraic mistake that I can't seem to find, or was my methodology incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify
$$\frac{(z-1)(i+1)}{(z+1)(i-1)}= \frac{(w-i+1)(i-1)}{(w-1+i)(1-i)}$$
again, you will find the map 
$$w=(-1-i)\dfrac{z-i}{z+i}$$
which is true. Another simple way is mapping unit circle to right half plane with $\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}$ and rotate it $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.